# Unable to access WMI on remote machine using vb.net

Tags: wmi, admin, vb.net-2010

I've had a scout around and can't seem to find the answer anywhere, so need to ask.

I'm trying to query the WMI on a remote machine, but I need to do so as the admin account and I'm having problems doing so.

The code I am using is:

```
Public Sub OperatingSystem(ByVal computeritem As String)
    'set Username and Password which system will access the network with.
    Dim options As ConnectionOptions
    options = New ConnectionOptions()
    options.Authority = "ntdlmdomain:" & ipaddress
    options.Username = "Username"
    options.Password = "Password"

    scope = New ManagementScope("\\" & ipaddress & "\root\cimv2", options)
    scope.Connect()

    Dim query As ObjectQuery
    query = New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
    Dim searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher
    searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)
```

the query continues to go and pull all kinds of information through to a spradsheet.. well it would if it worked!

The line of code that is falling over is:

```
scope = New ManagementScope("\\" & ipaddress & "\root\cimv2", options)
    scope.Connect()
```

It's giving me an error message that just says 'Invalid parameter'. When I go to view detail, there's nothing in inner exception and the only thing that I can see of any value is ErrorCode:ManagementStatus.InvalidParameter

I apologize if this is something really simple.. I am still fairly new to this but if someone could give me some guidance that would really be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes connecting WMI remotely using an IP address can be problematic - see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018686/wmi-cannot-connect-to-certain-computers-via-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reference to ipaddress is not initialized. Since computeritem is passed as a parameter to the sub, your code might work better with:

```
scope = New ManagementScope("\\" & computeritem & "\root\cimv2", options)
```