# c# connect to remote using wmi needs /etc/hosts

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I am using below code to connect remote computer however it needs that the remote computer must be exist at '@drivers/etc/hosts' file.

If i don't write the information about remote computer on /etc/hosts file it gives below error;

```
the rpc server is unavailable
```

How can i connect to rdp without modifying '@drivers/etc/hosts' file ?

```
public void GetSystemInformation()
        {

            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Username = "test";
            options.Password = "test";
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\someip\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();

            //Query system for Operating System information
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                // Display the remote computer information
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}",m["csname"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}", m["WindowsDirectory"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}", m["Caption"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}",m["Manufacturer"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to so rdp manually to that IP?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes i can do it.

Comment: Possibly related : [WMI - Cannot connect to certain computers via IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018686/wmi-cannot-connect-to-certain-computers-via-ip-address)

Comment: Add to the Options: `options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;`. If you are in NT Domain, `.Authority = "NTLMDOMAIN:<domain>"`. If not, your machine must have ComputerBrowser service running. 
Also, see what `IPHostEntry HostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("[someip]");` gives you back. You can see if it fails or `HostInfo.HostName` is correct.

Comment: Based on @stuartd 's comment, you probably have DNS and/or reverse DNS issues. What happens if you `ping -a ip` when it is not in `hosts`? You can also do `nslookup ip `to do a reverse DNS query directly.