# Identify a ping request to an IP address in C#?

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to know how to find out if a system is shutdown or not using its IP address (consider i have been provided list of IP addresses).

Currently i have a console application that is taking a command as an input and executing it on command prompt and showing me the output on the console.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process cmdProcess = new Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdProcess.Start();      
    }
}
```

Comment: The magical word is `ping`.

Comment: @Paxz, not all machines reply on pings.

Comment: Are you able to change the architecture a bit? The reason why I want to suggest this is, as far as I know, there wont be any way to check if the machine is there, without some changes on the client/remote machine side. If you could rather have a service/something running on the client side, that "checks in" on your host, it would work better.

Comment: It is impossible to create a GENERAL solution to this problem that doesn't run software on the remote host. The system might not respong to PING, might not be a Windows system (which makes using WMI impossible) or might not respond to network traffic at all if it's not a reply. What you need is a program on each remote host, that allows you to remote control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine is replying to pings, as per @Paxz 's suggestion, you can do this :

```
var ping = new Ping();
var pingReply = ping.Send("123.123.123.123");

if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-) to attempt to obtain the [`WMI_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) on the remote machine.

If you're able to access that object and have suitable permissions, you'll also be able to invoke its `Shutdown` method<sup>1</sup>.

Unlike `ping`, the above *verifies that you can connect to the machine for the purposes you actually need to*<sup>2</sup>.

(If connecting to WMI via IP address isn't working, you may wish to consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5018686/15498))

---

<sup>1</sup>I suppose there may be a perverse situation where, on the one hand, you have some form of permission to initiate remote shutdowns, but on the other some aspect of doing this via WMI is blocked, but that's really a push back to your administrators - you're being asked to perform an administrative task, the right route is WMI.

<sup>2</sup>ping just tells you that ICMP ECHO is being processed correctly by the remote machine<sup>3</sup>. It gives you no indication of whether the system is capable of *any other activity*. It's pointless to "pre-check" connectivity with ping if you're going to follow that up with other activity that requires connectivity *and other things* in order to work. Among other things, *between* running a "pre-check" and *acting on the outcome*, the *external reality* may have changed.

You'll need to write code that copes with network connectivity changing *whilst* you're attempting your activity *anyway* (or the remote machine going down for other reasons, etc).

<sup>3</sup>And that nothing is filtering ICMP ECHO traffic.