# Shutdown another system using its IP address in the command prompt by a c# program?

Tags: c#, cmd, system.diagnostics

I am working on a c# program that would pick up IP addresses from a notepad file, and for each IP address, if the system is powered on, it would run a command on command prompt that would remotely shut it down. I have written this code, that is currently picking up my system's IP address (not by notepad file currently), check if it is on or off, and on request, remotely shut it down.

It is using a ping request but that is fine because no system here is denying a ping request. What I want is to read the IP address and if it is on, shut it down if the user says "Yes". [I have used "shutdown \s" to shut down my system right now"] This is my code right now.

```
        Console.WriteLine("1-Check PC Status\n2-Exit");
        input = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (input)
        {
                case 1:
                    string LocalIP = string.Empty;
                    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
                    {
                        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            LocalIP = ip.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    var PingRequest = new Ping();
                    var PingReply = PingRequest.Send(LocalIP);
                    if (PingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0, -20} {1, 5}", "IP Address", "Status");
                        Console.WriteLine("{0, -20} {1, 5}", LocalIP, "On");
                        Console.WriteLine("\nShutdown the system (y/n)?");
                        string shutdownChoice;
                        shutdownChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                        if(shutdownChoice == "y" || shutdownChoice == "Y")
                        {
                            Process cmdProcess = new Process();
                            cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            cmdProcess.Start();

                            cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("shutdown /s");
                            cmdProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
                            cmdProcess.StandardInput.Close();
                            cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            input = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0, -20} {1, 5}", LocalIP, "Off");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    input = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input");
                    break;
            }
```

I know this command `shutdown \i` but this will open up a dialog to enter the IP addresses but I want to shut it down right through the console without having any additional dialog or window. `shutdown \m //computername` isn't working as well.

Apologies for a very lengthy description.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you always write `\ ` instead of `/`?

Comment: Does the user who's running your application have the permissions to shut down the remote PC? Maybe you should start `shutdown` as administrator.

Comment: Sorry for "\", that's mistyping, i used "/" in the command, and yes permissions are granted.

Comment: this code is not opening any dialogue did you check this?

Comment: This doesn't seem much different from [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499419/find-if-system-is-shutdown-or-not-using-its-ip-address-through-c-sharp-program) where you haven't provided any *feedback* to the answers you were provided. Why are you so obsessed with *running other programs* to accomplish tasks when you're writing a program yourself and there are *programmatic* approaches you can take?

Comment: Why would you test if the ipaddress is on. Just shut it down. Programmers use programming interfaces not pretend to type user's commands. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/shutdown-method-in-class-win32-operatingsystem

Comment: @CatCat i wouldn't run shutdown commands on those that are already powered off to save execution time.

Comment: You aren't saving execution time. You are doubling it if most computers are on, and equalling it if most computers aren't. So programmers **do** and, if it matters, **tests** the result of doing.

Comment: `ping`ing a machine that doesn't answer (without changing default settings) is one of the *slowest* things you can do. By default, you won't get a negative response for *5 seconds*, which is an eternity in computing terms.

Comment: Apart from the programming pattern of doing and testing (testing the result of a do is very quick). There is also the concept of **taxes**. Taxes are computer overheads. Different operating systems do the overhead at different times. In Windows most overheads are levied at process creation (so all other operations on that process are quick) and window creation (for the same reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `shutdown /s /f /m \\computername`

If this doesn´t work, I would recommend checking out PsTools suite. They have some command line tools and PsShutdown could help.